# How to get summary of pivot rows in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've a query:

```
WITH dane AS (
SELECT PACJENT.PLEC, JOS.NAZWA
FROM PACJENT
INNER JOIN POBYT ON PACJENT.ID_PAC = POBYT.ID_PAC
INNER JOIN JOS ON JOS.IDK_JOS = POBYT.IDK_JOS
WHERE trunc(months_between(POBYT.DT_OD,PACJENT.DATA_UR)/12)> 65)
SELECT NAZWA,K,M ,K+M as suma FROM dane
PIVOT (
COUNT(*)
FOR PLEC
IN ('M' as K,'K' as M)
)
```

and output like:

```
Radioterapia        2056    1775    3831
Poradnia WZW        689     909     1598
Ambulatorium ogólne 705     1150    1855
```

But I need total row for all columns:

```
    Radioterapia        2056    1775    3831
    Poradnia WZW        689     909     1598
    Ambulatorium ogólne 705     1150    1855
    ---
    TOTAL               3450    3834    7284
```

How can i do this? Thanks for advance.

Comment: Since you've tagged this with SQL Developer, do you mean [COMPUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve014.htm), or are you trying to generate this extra line in the result set in SQL rather than having the client handle it?

Comment: I try to generate this in extra line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need to extract the total row with a SQL query, you can try wrapping your query with something like this:

```
    WITH dane AS
         (SELECT PACJENT.PLEC, JOS.NAZWA
            FROM PACJENT
                 INNER JOIN POBYT ON PACJENT.ID_PAC = POBYT.ID_PAC
                 INNER JOIN JOS ON JOS.IDK_JOS = POBYT.IDK_JOS
           WHERE TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(POBYT.DT_OD, PACJENT.DATA_UR) / 12) > 65)
  SELECT NAZWA,
         SUM(K),
         SUM(M),
         SUM(SUMA)
    FROM (SELECT NAZWA,
                 K,
                 M,
                 K + M AS suma
            FROM dane PIVOT (COUNT(*) FOR PLEC IN ('M' AS K, 'K' AS M)))
GROUP BY ROLLUP(NAZWA)
```

Comment: Ok, it's work in this case, but my query is dynamc. So i need some code in this query:
`WITH dane AS (
SELECT PACJENT.PLEC, JOS.NAZWA
FROM PACJENT
INNER JOIN POBYT ON PACJENT.ID_PAC = POBYT.ID_PAC
INNER JOIN JOS ON JOS.IDK_JOS = POBYT.IDK_JOS
WHERE trunc(months_between(POBYT.DT_OD,PACJENT.DATA_UR)/12)> 65)
SELECT NAZWA,K,M ,K+M as suma FROM dane
PIVOT (
COUNT(*)
FOR PLEC
IN ('M' as K,'K' as M)
)`

Comment: Edited the answer to better fit  your query